# Using the Code Iris or SketchIt! plugins in PhpStorm 2019.2

Tags: phpstorm

I need a tool to generate UML from my PHP classes and [Code Iris](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324-code-iris) looked like it could do that.  Well, from the screenshots anyway.  There isn't anything on the plugin page or on their home page describing how to actually use the plugin.  Same with the [SketchIt!](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10387-sketch-it-) plugin.

However, there is no reference to either one of them in any of the menu bar menus nor in any of the right click context menus.  I don't see any errors when loading PhpStorm like there have been in the past when it tries to load an incompatible plugin.

So what do I need to actually utilize either of these plugins?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used either. Code Iris screenshots show a tab beside *Database* and Sketch It! page says "go to the Tools menu and select "Sketch It!". Can you see those elements? I may also help to use *Help/ Find Action* and type the plugins names.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've tried the "Help/Find Action" thing and it came back with nothing.  I'm not seeing either one anywhere, whether that is a tab or in the Tools menu.  This is why I'm totally flummoxed.  When I go to Settings -> Plugins I see that they are installed and that they are enabled but nothing... :(

Comment: None of the mentioned plugins is capable of doing what you are looking for. Sketch It! is a plugin that generates diagrams from PlantUML code, and Code Iris is designed for Java/Groovy. None of them support PHP. Doesn't the built-in feature do the trick for you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/class-diagram.html